# Realm support maven or having jar of it's latest source

Tags: android, maven, realm, realm-migration

I am having bit weird use case here, My project is divided in 2 modules one is server-project and another is android-app, Now they both are sharing same model classes. Server-project using maven build tool in eclipse and android-app using gradle in Android studio.

Looks like realm not having maven artifact and also not found jar file of latest version.

Please help me to figure out bit weird case.

Comment: Currently maven is not supported. The relevant issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2342

Comment: Only Gradle is supported, because Realm uses the Transform API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put kind of hack into model to share between android and shared server project.

You can make dummy realm classes for you server which can exclude by gradle and you need to create same exact class in same exact package.
Classes for server:

```
package io.realm;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RealmObject extends ArrayList
{

}

package io.realm;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RealmList<E> extends ArrayList
{

}
```

Shared project gradle should ignore dummy class and can use realm class:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.0.2"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java {
                srcDirs 'src'
                //Exclude server (fake) Realm dependent files to avoid conflicts with Realm framework
                exclude '**/Ignore.java'
                exclude '**/RealmObject.java'
                exclude '**/RealmList.java'
                exclude '**/PrimaryKey.java'
            }
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['aidl']
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}
```

NOTE: Server still have no support of realm. we just tweak to support android and server to work.

Final model:

```
import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class MyModel extends RealmObject
```